# this apache RewriteRule can not working,and is specail

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

this is my apache rewrite rules

```
RewriteRule  ^info info.php
```

and is can worked,like vistor http://www.a.com/info

but when i use

```
RewriteRule  ^info-([0-9]+) info.php
```

this can not work,like vistor http://www.a.com/info-01

i think mod_rewrite likes can not worked "-" and backgroud.

when i use "`-`"->"`\-`" and can not working too..

so i don't konw how to work? any body can help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "does work" and "does _not_ work"? What exactly? Any errors you get, or just no reaction?

Comment: yes,i mean is  "does work" and "does not work".

Comment: no any errors,just no reaction

Comment: You're not even giving an example what kind of URL it's "not working" with.

Comment: when i use http://www.a.com/info-11 to vistor,rewrite can not work.

Answer (score 0):

ok,this question cause by i can not set

```
AllowOverride ALL
```

in httpd.conf